# добавить колонку с Count строк в каждой ячейкен по Row_number

Tags: sql-server, функции

Всем привет.

Есть таблица, в которую нужно добавить колонку с Count строк в каждой ячейке по Row_number. Никак не получается сделать.

Используется DevExpress Dashboard designer (что исключает возможность добавления временных таблиц, только запросы через SELECT) на MS SQL Server 2016.

Пример таблицы находится тут: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8829b69ca8c01391fa6762fa9470c66b

Исходная таблица в результате запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: вы словами вообще задачу в состоянии описать? что имеется в исходных, и что надо посчитать. Есть у вас 3 столбца. Приложите исходные данные, и по какому принципу надо получить результат.

Comment: Что не так в моем описании? Все предельно ясно: Получить количество строк по Row_Number в каждой ячейке в отдельной колонке. Скрины приложены.

Comment: Вот ссылка на фиддл где я пытался вывести требуемый результат: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c3f459a078a8a68e54eaa58b9eacfdf. К сожалению, мне выводит или 0 или 1 в каждой ячейке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

временные таблицы тут в общем то ни к чему, можно использовать cte или подзапрос для выборки.

```
with data as (
    select 
    case when c.client_central = 'true' then c.client_name
         when c.client_central = 'false' 
           and c.client_assigned_to is null then c.client_name
         else c1.client_name
       end as cc
   from clients as c
   left join clients as c1 on c.client_assigned_to = c1.oid
)
select cc
      ,row_number() over(partition by cc order by cc)
      ,count(*) over (partition by cc)
from data
order by cc;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: В случае с созданной таблицой Ваше решение подходит, спасибо (http://prntscr.com/wwicld). Но, как указал в вопросе, в случае с devexpress dashboard designer, решение должно входить в скрипт, который начинается с SELECT (http://prntscr.com/wwi9x9). Поэтому проблема остается актуальной.

Comment: Вот так выглядит исходник из devexpress dashboard designer: http://prntscr.com/wwjnk4

Comment: @user421875 тогда CTE перенесите  в подзапрос `select ... from (....) as data`

Comment: пока не знаю как это сделать, я не профессионал в SQL. Отпишу когда найду решение.

Comment: Всае оказалось проще http://prntscr.com/wz1qcw Спасибо.